# What am I missing to compile, run and debug VSCode from within VSCode?

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, build, yarnpkg

I am trying to compile, run and debug VSCode according to the [How to Contribute](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute) guideline.
I would like to do this locally, *not* with a development container or within WSL2. I have completed these steps:

- Installed Node v16.16.0
- Installed yarn
- Installed the ''Desktop Development with C++' workload for VS 2022
- Forked and cloned the VS Code repo
- ran `yarn` on it
- Started the Build Task with `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `B`
- After a few minutes started the 'Launch VS Code' launch config from within 'Run and Debug'

This fails to start (Unable to find a debugable target). So then I tried running `./scripts/code.bat` directly. I get the following output and subsequent error:

```
PS D:\repos\vscode> .\scripts\code.bat
yarn run v1.22.19
$ node build/lib/electron
Done in 0.31s.
[20:11:44] Synchronizing built-in extensions...
[20:11:44] You can manage built-in extensions with the --builtin flag
[20:11:44] [github] ms-vscode.js-debug-companion@1.0.18 ✔︎
[20:11:44] [github] ms-vscode.js-debug@1.69.0 ✔︎
[20:11:44] [github] ms-vscode.vscode-js-profile-table@1.0.2 ✔︎
'".build\electron\Code - OSS.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I noticed that I don't have a .build folder.
How can I start to compile, run and debug VSCode from source?

// Edit:

Following the instructions for [Selfhosting on WSL](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Selfhosting-on-Windows-WSL) works and I get a 'Code - OSS' window as expected. [image: Code OSS on Windows 11 in WSL2]

Comment: since when do you compile NodeJS stuff

Comment: @rioV8 since VSCode I guess, but see my edit, it works within WSL2